# "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" AWT java

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awt, nosuchmethoderror

I want this program to display on the spot on the screen where I clicked a rectangle **Shape** already created in **Contenaire** class.
I wanted to make it based on this awt hierarchy **Component->Container->Frame** so that I don't make mistakes but I still did.
So why is it showing me this error ? :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void DessinComponent.(java.awt.Shape, java.awt.Color, int, int)'

This is my first time working with java so am still learning.

One of the answers that I found was :

> That's the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Code involving AWT or Swing should be run on that thread. This is the thread you'll be on when in you main (running in the "main" thread) you typically call java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater

I added **java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater** and still nothing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double;



public class TestGraphic2 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.setSize(600, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.add(new Contenaire());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

 class Contenaire extends Container {
    
    private Shape shape;
    private DessinComponent composant;
    public Contenaire() {
        super();
        setLayout(null);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        setSize(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(160, 220, 100, 40);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    
                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();
                        
                        composant = new DessinComponent(shape,Color.green,x,y);
                        add(composant);
                    }
                
            
        });
    }
}

class DessinComponent extends Component {
   
    private Shape shape;
    private Color color;

    public DessinComponent(Shape shape, Color color, int x, int y) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.color = color;
        //setLocation(0, 0);
        //setSize(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.draw(shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line throws this exception? I don't think the posted code reproduces the error.

Comment: @c0der I think row 45 !

Comment: *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:* - seems like you have an old class file with an improper constructor. Delete all your class files and recompile. Also, why are you using AWT components? You should be using either Swing or JavaFx. You should NOT be extending Container. I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html). It will show you how to paint a rectangle and the point your click.

Comment: The posted code does not throw this exception. (In general, you should post the entire stacktrace and mark the line that throws the exception with a comment)